# How to horizontally align an image with a list from the top?

Tags: html, css

The image inside the first div is supposed to be horizontally aligned with the list in the second div from the top. But as you can see the list has a gap with the top. Please kindly guide how to remove this gap?

FIDDLE:  https://jsfiddle.net/sryzdn/svg0716k/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="div1"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100"></div>
  <div id="div2">
    <ul>
      <li>aaa</li>
      <li>bbb</li>
      <li>ccc</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
}

#div1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

#div1 img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

#div2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  positive: relative;
}

#div2 ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

#div2 li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: `ul {margin: 0}` ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `top:0` property and add `margin-top: 0px` in `#div2 ul`;

```
#div2 ul {
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `margin-top: 0px` for your `<ul>`.  See [new fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/uwo6jfsk/1/)

Answer (score 0):

see this https://jsfiddle.net/0guuehj8/

comment postiton absolute and redefine padding

```
  #div2 ul {
  /*position: absolute;
   top: 0;*/
  margin:0px;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
  padding: 0;
}
```